# Java Unmarshalling an XML file using JAXB without knowing the tags

Tags: java, xml, csv, jaxb, xjb

So I have about 950 XML files that I need to read, I have the Java classes for those XML files generated using an .xsd and a binding .xjb file.
My problem is that I need this code to be interchangeable, meaning it must be able to read different XML files with different tags, and still be able to return these values. I've tried using method.invoke to invoke all the get methods, but they aren't returned in a specific order, which doesn't help since I will need these values in an order to place it in a .csv file.
So if anyone can help me achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the tags are different (and the files don't have a common schema anymore), how is the same code supposed to parse it? If this needs to be dynamic, staticly generated bindings are probably not the way to go. Try something like XPath. But still, you need to tell the code something about the structure of the file, even if that happens at runtime with some heuristics.

Comment: If you don't know the tags, don't use JAXB. You may use SAX, Xerces etc...

Comment: If your goal is to transform the XMLs into CSV, XSLT could be a better option

Comment: You could consider transforming (using XSLT) the XML schema file by modifying the element (and, perhaps, attribute) @name attributes in the `<xsd:element>` elements, provided the .xsd file isn't too "fancy". Then, generate the Java classes. You may have to write a couple of lines for the "main" method if the root element name changes, too. --- As an alternative, consider using a sed or Perl script to transform the XML files. Element tags are rather easy to identify without having to parse XML accurately --- You may also use an XSLT transformation for the XML files. --- I'd use the last option.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I have to use JAXB and the code has to be generic i.e. be able to work for a lot of different .xsd files, so I am going to read the XmlType annotation in the generated classes and use the propOrder to call the getMethods in the correct order and just use a printWriter to create the .csv

Comment: JAXB will not unmarshall XML files with element names ("tags") that don't agree with the XML schema.